# Post an Array in Javascript to Node.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, post, get

First thank you for trying to help me.
I want to know how pass(post,get) an Array in JS to Node.js backend to parse it then.
This is my Array:

```
var Coordinates = [
      {lat: 37.772, lng: -122.214},
      {lat: 21.291, lng: -157.821},
      {lat: -18.142, lng: 178.431},
      {lat: -27.467, lng: 153.027}
                              ];
```

In the real stage, this Array is created when the user click the Google map. But this Array is an example what i need to send to my Node.js backend.
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do `JSON.stringify()`. This will convert your array into a string, which can be passed across the network via GET or POST. In the node server, you can parse this string and get the array using `JSON.parse`. Adding a working Example below

```js
var Coordinates = [
      {lat: 37.772, lng: -122.214},
      {lat: 21.291, lng: -157.821},
      {lat: -18.142, lng: 178.431},
      {lat: -27.467, lng: 153.027}
                              ];

var a = JSON.stringify(Coordinates)
console.log('Coordinates string: ', a)

var parsed = JSON.parse(a)
console.log('Parsed Coordinates: ', parsed)
```

Comment: How can i Parse with node.js, i have this code in my backend, but it does not work:
var jsonParser = bodyParser.json()
app.post(':8081/load_coordinates',jsonParser, function(request, response){
  var parsed = JSON.parse(request.body)
  console.log(parsed); 
});
app.listen(8081);

In my frontend i have this:
  function httpPOST(data)
{
    var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "http://localhost:8081/load_coordinates";
    client.open("POST", url, true);
    client.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
    client.send(data);
}

Comment: You can do `JSON.parse()` in node js too.